# postgresql 9.4/9.5 - Select (constant value) as id from generate_series - How does this query work?

Tags: postgresql

I don't understand how this query works

```
select * from users
where id in (
  select round(random() * 21e6)::integer as id
  from generate_series(1, 110) -- Preserve duplicates
)
limit 100
```

source: https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/how-to-sample-rows-in-sql-273x-faster.html

If I try to translate in natural language, it would be:

- select * from users where id in...=> select all users who have an id inside the values...
- select round(random() * 21e6)::integer as id => how can you select a number, here it's like "select 3500 as id". I thought that usually you select a column like for example 'select company_name as name ???' and not 'select 15 as name'
- from generate_series(1, 110)=> how can you have select 3500 as id then tell him to select 3500 from a series (1,2,3,...,108,109,110)

I really don't understand this complex query.

Can someone help me understand each step ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea about the main query, but seem to mostly confused by the subquery. Let me see if I can explain:

The basic idea is that you're wanting to get 110 random numbers. You use random() to get the number, apply some math to turn it into the sort of number you're looking for, and select from `generate_series` to repeat the process 110 times.

Now let's break it down in detail. Let's start with a basic select statement:

`select some_number from some_table;`

But instead of a normal table, let's use generate_series. It's a function  that returns a table with one column. This query returns 110 rows containing the numbers 1 to 110:

`select generate_series from generate_series(1, 110);`

It returns a number, so you could do some math on the number:

`select generate_series * 2 + 3500 from generate_series(1, 110);`

but what if we do this: (You'd agree it should work, right?)

`select generate_series * 0 + 3500 from generate_series(1, 110);`

that's exactly like saying:

`select 3500 from generate_series(1, 110);`

which is like saying:

`select 3500::integer from generate_series(1, 110);`

and, since any integer works, you could also do this:

`select round(random() * 21e6)::integer from generate_series(1, 110);`

Lastly, you could rename the column like so:

`select round(random() * 21e6)::integer as id from generate_series(1, 110);`

... and there's your query.